# Solving an integral of form $ F(x)=\int (2x-1)e^{2x}\ dx $

Tags: integration, exponential-function

I have this integral in a worksheet please help me solve it

> $$ F(x)=\int (2x-1)e^{2x}\ dx $$

Comment: please correct the question's format !

Comment: Is that right? $e^2x$ or $e^{2x}$?

Comment: @Kaster I'm pretty sure $e^{2x}$ is correct.

Comment: Yes thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u = (2x - 1)$ and $dv = e^{2x}dx$. Now continue with integration by parts.

Answer (score 0):

You have a product... if you differentiate the first term of the product and integrate the second, the integral simplifies.